# Object only stores one property when added to NSMutableArray

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsmutablearray

I am trying to store a Location Object (Title, Description, CLLocation) in an NSMutableArray however only the description is being added to the array. All the properties are available yet only the description text is being added to the array rather than the object. What am I doing wrong?

```
        NSMutableArray *locArray= [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
        ...

        NSLog(@"myLoc : %@", myLoc);
        NSString *title = myLoc [@"title"];
        NSString *desc = myLoc [@"description"]; 
        PFGeoPoint *geoPoint = [[PFGeoPoint alloc]init];
        geoPoint = [myLoc objectForKey:@"location"];//location; 
        NSLog(@"GEO POINT : %f", geoPoint.latitude);


        PDLocation *PDLoc = [[PDLocation alloc]initWithName:title description:desc andLocation:CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(geoPoint.latitude, geoPoint.longitude)];
        NSLog (@"PDLOC : %@", PDLoc.name);
        NSLog (@"PDLOC : %@", PDLoc.description);
        NSLog (@"PDLOC : %f", PDLoc.location.latitude);
        [locArray addObject:PDLoc] ;
```

Comment: Is this because you are printing the contents of the array? If so, only `description` would get printed to the console (default behaviour), not every property gets printed. If you put a breakpoint at you first `NSLog` statement, can you view the properties of `PDLocation` in the debugger?

Comment: Thanks Mike. No, the program crashes downstream because the Array objects are not properly populated. Only the description text gets added to the array, not the object.

Comment: what do yo have in you init method ?

Comment: i guess `init` is written in loop, so it create new array each time. check it.

Comment: Again, I think you are overriding the default `description` method (intended or not). If the problem appears "downstream," please post the relevant code, and any log output related to the crash. [Setting an exception breakpoint](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-breakpoint_navigator/articles/adding_an_exception_breakpoint.html) may help tracking the problem down.

Comment: Thanks for everyone's help on this. The information is actually there and as Mike D stated, only description is available so it was working all along. There was another issue downstream which compounded this. I had not set my location manually so when the map displayed, it came up empty. I've learned that even if location services is set to on, if you don't set your "current location" things go screwy which was more or less the source of this post.  Thanks again everyone.